# What is the relationship between the width, height, and radius of an arc?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

What is the relationship between the width ($w$), height ($h$), and radius ($r$) of an arc?

Specifically, the relationship in terms of $h$.

I know this is a simple question - I'm a hobbyist engineer, and I'm having one of those moments, where your mind goes blank and you can't remember the simplest thing.

[image]

Comment: I don't think most people would consider what you drew as the width or height of the arc.  I think most would think the width refers to the length of the chord (from point on the circle to point on the circle) and the height as the distance between midpoint of chord to midpoint of arc.  Se my answer.  I answered both interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Picture]

$w^2+(r-h)^2=r^2$

$w^2+r^2-2hr+h^2=r^2$

$h^2-2hr+w^2=0$

Quadratic in $h$.

Solution:

$h=\frac{2r\pm\sqrt{4r^2-4w^2}}{2}$

The positive case is rejected, leaving us with:

$h=\frac{2r-\sqrt{4r^2-4w^2}}{2}$

$h=r-\sqrt{r^2-w^2}$

The proof that the positive case is rejected is left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: Quadratic formula:  h = $\frac{2r \pm \sqrt{4r^2 - 4w^2}}{2} = r \pm \sqrt{r^2 - w^2}$.  Note this answers assumes the arc is less than a 1/4 of the circle.

Comment: @Giffyguy Done.

Comment: @KennyLau does the arc have to be completely contained in a quadrant?. For example, if we rotate the arc such that it's mid point lies on the $y$ axis, doesn't $h$ and $w$ change?

Comment: @LuisVera No. In that case, $w=0$, and $h=r-\sqrt{r^2-0^2}=r-r=0$

Answer (score 2):

Another take.

Let $(0,-r)$ and $(x, y)$ be the endpoints of the arc.  Then

$h = |r - y|$ and $w = |x|$.

We know $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ so $h = |r \pm \sqrt{r^2 - w^2}| = r \pm \sqrt{r^2 - w^2}$. And $w = |x| = \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} = \sqrt{r^2 - (h-r)^2} = \sqrt{2hr - h^2}$

=====

However not your interpretation of width and height are a little odd.  You assume you are lying the arc on its tangent (like pressing one end of a clipped toenail to the floor) and measuring the displacement.

I think most people would assume the width is the measure from endpoint to endpoint and the height to be the displace of *that*. (Like leaving the toenail balancing one its center and measuring how high and far apart the ends are).

(The difference between the new picture and your picture is in the new picture the radius goes *through* the arc cutting it in half.  The height is from the midpoint of the chord to the tip of the circle, and the width is the length of a chord.)

(In Your picture the chord is the hypotenuse slanting upward. Width is the horizontal leg and the height is the vertical leg.  I think most would view the chord itself as the width, and the height as the perpendicular bisector of the chord to the circle.)

In this case the endpoints are $(-x,y)$ and $(x,y)$ and

$w = 2x$ and $h = r - y$.  Using $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ we get:

$w = 2\sqrt{r^2 - (r-h)^2} = 2\sqrt{2hr - h^2}$ and

$h = r \pm \sqrt{r^2 - ((1/2)w)^2} = r \pm \sqrt {r^2 - w^2/4}$.

====

Note.  Given an arc's width and length you can calculate the radius of the circle.

I probably should have included those as well.

In your picture:  $(r-h)^2 + w^2 = r^2$ so $w^2 = 2hr - h^2$ so $r = (h^2 + w^2)/2h$.

In mine:  $(r-h)^2 + (w/2)^2 = r^2$ so $w^2/4 = 2hr - h^2$ so $r = (h^2 + w^2/4)/2h$.